# Need a widget in flutter for text editing like word

Tags: flutter, text-editor

Just started with flutter.
I want to implement a text part where the user can see and edit their texts directly. I don‘t want to insert handwritten text. It‘s only about text from keyboard. As features I want to add things like writing bold/cursive text or adding bullet points. Nothing special.
My question is if it‘s okay to use one of the rich text editors or if I should use a canvas and create my text fields on it?

Best greets